# Sql Workbench does not work on macOs venture latest version

Tags: mysql, macos, mysql-workbench

[image]

When ever I try to launch the MySql workbench it crashes and shows this error report.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling different versions it shows same error.

Comment: Even if this is not related to programming: did you try to search for this problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65792436/mysqlworkbench-quit-unexpectedly-on-macos-big-sur-11-1 contains hints, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60864776/macos-unable-to-run-mysql-workbench also

Comment: Which version of MySQL WB you have? 8.0.32 [supports Ventura](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/). If this happens with up-to-date Ventura and MySQL WB, I'd probably delete the question and drop it to the Apple SE site [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com).

Comment: MySQL Workbench 8.0.32 on Mac is known to crash on any query. https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=109671 The workaround is to download an older version.